# Use @blur event in flatpickr, when output is null

Tags: vue.js

```html
<b-col md="7" offset-md="1">
  <b-form-group>
    <template>
      Time
      <flat-pickr
        id="time"
        v-model="time"
        class="form-control"
        :config="timeConfig"
        @blur="valTime"
      />
  </template>
 </b-form-group>
</b-col>
```

```js
data() {
  return: {
   time: null,
   timeConfig: {
     dateFormat: 'Y-m-d H:i',
   }
  }
},
methods: {
  valTime(e) {
    console.log(e.target.value) // null
  }
}
```

I am doing vuejs. I use @blur event in flatpickr it returns null, is there any way I can get the result, where did I go wrong, please advise. Thanks

Comment: Why not use `onChange`?https://flatpickr.js.org/events/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`flat-pickr` emits the `onChange` event when the user selects a new date. The event handler (i.e., `valTime()` in this case) receives three arguments, but you can just use the first argument to get the selected date:

```js
export default {
  methods: {
    valTime(selectedDates, dateStr, instance) {
      console.log(selectedDates)
    }
  }
}
```

The [`vue-flatpickr-component` docs](https://github.com/ankurk91/vue-flatpickr-component#events) describe how to listen to `onChange`:

```html
<flat-pickr ⋯ @on-change="valTime" />
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-handle-change-events-from-flat-pickr?file=src/App.vue)